# How to filter by the size of an array in nested type?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

Let's say I have the following type:

```
{
    "2019-11-04": {
        "mappings": {
            "_doc": {
                "properties": {
                    "labels": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "confidence": {
                                "type": "float"
                            },
                            "created_at": {
                                "type": "date",
                                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||date_time||epoch_millis"
                            },
                            "label": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "updated_at": {
                                "type": "date",
                                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||date_time||epoch_millis"
                            },
                            "value": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "fields": {
                                    "numeric": {
                                        "type": "float",
                                        "ignore_malformed": true
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "params": {
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "type": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to filter by the size/length of the `labels` array. I've tried the following ([as the official docs suggest](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/query-dsl-script-query.html)):

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "script": {
                    "script": {
                        "source": "doc['labels'].size > 10"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I keep getting:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "runtime error",
        "script_stack": [
          "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:81)",
          "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:39)",
          "doc['labels'].size > 10",
          "    ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script": "doc['labels'].size > 10",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "2019-11-04",
        "node": "kk5MNRPoR4SYeQpLk2By3A",
        "reason": {
          "type": "script_exception",
          "reason": "runtime error",
          "script_stack": [
            "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:81)",
            "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:39)",
            "doc['labels'].size > 10",
            "    ^---- HERE"
          ],
          "script": "doc['labels'].size > 10",
          "lang": "painless",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "No field found for [labels] in mapping with types []"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

Comment: hey @Patryk just wanted to see if you were able to resolve the above query. Was the below answer useful in any way.

Comment: @Kamal In a sense, yes. I understood that I need a different way to tackle this. I haven't found a way to do in the way I'd like, though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that is not something possible, because the field `labels` is not a field that ES saves or albiet creates an inverted index on.

Doc `doc['fieldname']` is only applicable on the fields on which inverted index is created and Elasticsearch's Query DSL too only works on fields on which inverted index gets created and unfortunately `nested` type is not a valid field on which inverted index is created.

Having said so, I have the below two ways of doing this.

For the sake of simplicity, I've created sample mapping, documents and two possible solutions which may help you.

### Mapping:

```
PUT my_sample_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "myfield": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "label": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Documents:

```
// single field inside 'myfield'
POST my_sample_index/_doc/1
{
  "myfield": {                              
    "label": ["New York", "LA", "Austin"]   
  }
}


// two fields inside 'myfield' 
POST my_sample_index/_doc/2
{                                          
  "myfield": {                             
    "label": ["London", "Leicester", "Newcastle", "Liverpool"],
    "country": "England"
  }
}
```

### Solution 1: Using [Script Fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/search-request-script-fields.html) (Managing at Application Level)

I have a workaround to get what you want, well not exactly but would help you filter out on your service layer or application.

```
POST my_sample_index/_search
{
  "_source": "*", 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "label_size": {
        "script": {
            "lang": "painless",
            "source": "params['_source']['labels'].size() > 1"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

You would notice that in response a separate field `label_size` gets created with `true` or `false` value.

**A sample response is something like below:**

```
{
  "took" : 5,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_sample_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "myfield" : {
            "label" : [
              "New York",
              "LA",
              "Austin"
            ]
          }
        },
        "fields" : {
          "label_size" : [              <---- Scripted Field
            false
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_sample_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "myfield" : {
            "country" : "England",
            "label" : [
              "London",
              "Leicester",
              "Newcastle",
              "Liverpool"
            ]
          }
        },
        "fields" : {                  <---- Scripted Field
          "label_size" : [
            true                      <---- True because it has two fields 'labels' and 'country'
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that only second document makes sense as it has two fields i.e. `country` and `labels`. However if you only want the docs with `label_size` with `true`, that'd would have to be managed at your application layer.

### Solution 2: [Reindexing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) with labels.size using [Script Processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/script-processor.html)

**Create a new index as below:**

```
PUT my_sample_index_temp
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "myfield": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "label": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "labels_size":{             <---- New Field where we'd store the size
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Create the below pipeline:**

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/set_labels_size
{
  "description": "sets the value of labels size",
  "processors": [
      {
        "script": {
          "source": """
            ctx.labels_size = ctx.myfield.size();
          """
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

**Use Reindex API to reindex from `my_sample_index` index**

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "my_sample_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "my_sample_index_temp",
    "pipeline": "set_labels_size"
  }
}
```

**Verify the documents in `my_sample_index_temp` using `GET my_sample_index_temp/_search`**

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_sample_index_temp",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "labels_size" : 1,           <---- New Field Created 
          "myfield" : {
            "label" : [
              "New York",
              "LA",
              "Austin"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_sample_index_temp",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "labels_size" : 2,           <----- New Field Created
          "myfield" : {
            "country" : "England",
            "label" : [
              "London",
              "Leicester",
              "Newcastle",
              "Liverpool"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now you can simply use this field `labels_size` in your query and its way easier and not to mention efficient.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with a custom score approach:

```
GET 2019-11-04/_search
{
  "min_score": 0.1,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": "params['_source']['labels'].length > 10 ? 1 : 0"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```