# ElasticSearch 6.7 painless, how to access nested document

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

When I use ES 5.5 update to 6.7.
Painless script does’t work

This is 5.5 
If I want get a nested document [transFilter]
I do this

```
params['_source’]['carFilter’]
```

It  works very well。

But

When I used 6.7 version

params['_source’]['carFilter’]

I found it does’t work

All params['_source’] is null

my mappings

```
carFilter": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "time": {
              "type": "long"
            }
          }
        }
```

my data example

```
"carFilter" : [
            {
              "time" : 20200120
            },
            {
              "time" : 20200121
            }
          ]
```

and my query script example

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        {
          "script" : {
            "script" : {
               "inline" : "if(params['_source']!=null){
                             if(params['_source']['carFilter']!=null){   
                                 for(def item:params['_source']['carFilter'] ){
                                    if (item.time>1) {   return true; }
                                 }
                              }
                            }
                             return false;",
              "lang" : "painless",
              "params" : {
                "rentTime" : 1000
              }
            }
          }
        }      
      ] 
    }
  }
}
```

even no error
but fact

```
if(params['_source']!=null){
```

this line already return

The simple painless above is just to illustrate the problem, and a relatively real one is attached below.

```
double carPrice=0.00;if(!params['_source'].empty){"+
                " def days=params['_source']['everyDayPrice'];if(params['_source']['everyDayPrice']!=null){int size=days.length;" +
                " if(size>0){for(int i=0;i<size;i++){String day = days[i]['day'];Double price = days[i]['price'];"+
                " if(price!=null&&params.get(day)!=null){carPrice=carPrice+params.get(day)*price;}}}}}" +
                " return carPrice/params.total"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your query, you would want to filter the documents having `carFilter.time > 1` and why not use a simple [Nested Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html):

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "carFilter",
            "query": {
              "range": {
                "carFilter.time": {
                  "gte": 1
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I've made use of [Range Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) to evaluate the time based on what you are looking for.

I'd suggest you go through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58699142/3838328) if the above doesn't help.

Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: really really  thanks for your answer. this script just deliberate simplification to illustrate the problem. please tell me how to use the painless access nested document. thanks

Comment: @brooks so sorry for delay in reply. I guess that is not possible post ES version 6 onwards I think. I've shared another answer link which can help you but with what you have I don't think its possible anymore.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer..I have tried to read the official documents, but I have not found any usage for access nested document. So do you know how to do it,Or where should I go to find the answer?

Comment: @brooks I do not think it is possible to do something like that post ES 6.x versions. You may have to employ either of the two solutions I've mentioned in the link which I've mentioned in the answer.