# How to filter on nested document length by script in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to filter documents that have at least a given amount of items in a nested field, but I keep getting the following exception:

> "caused_by" : {
> "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
> "reason" : "No field found for [items] in mapping"
> }

Here's an example code to reproduce:

```
PUT store
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "subject": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "items": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "count": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST store/_bulk?refresh=true
{"create":{"_index":"store","_id":"1"}}
{"type":"appliance","items":[{"name":"Color TV"}]}
{"create":{"_index":"store","_id":"2"}}
{"type":"vehicle","items":[{"name":"Car"},{"name":"Bicycle"}]}
{"create":{"_index":"store","_id":"3"}}
{"type":"instrument","items":[{"name":"Guitar"},{"name":"Piano"},{"name":"Drums"}]}

GET store/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "source": "doc['items'].size() > 1"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that this is only a simplified filter script of what I really wanted to do, and if I can get over this, I will probable be able to solve my task as well.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58697508/how-to-filter-by-the-size-of-an-array-in-nested-type have some recommendations

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it with a custom score approach:

```
GET store/_search
{
  "min_score": 0.1,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": "params['_source']['items'].length > 1 ? 1 : 0"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```